# Temporarily disable alerts in specific list in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, alert

We need to do a maintenance that will modify a lot of items in a list where the is a lot of alerts.
We don't want to send notifications to the users and we can't simply delete the subscriptions (the alerts need to be enabled after the change).

I have seen solutions for doing that in SharePoint on-premises, from using stsadm to direct updates in the database... is there any way to achieve that in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Approximately how many alerts has been created on your SharePoint List??

Comment: @GaneshSanap, is there any way to get this information? I could see on "User Alerts" in "Site Settings" that there are about 60-70 users with alerts in the site. I haven't checked them all, but it seems that most of them target this list and another one.
I'm considering that we might need to do another maintenance like this in the future as well.

Comment: are you talking about email alerts or webhook subscription !!

Comment: @Milind, Email alerts, when the end user go to the list and create a alert for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Milind for the idea. My code to disable the alerts for a list:

```
#Title of the list:
$listTitle = "Your List Name"

#Connecting to the site where the list lives, it will ask for the credential:
Connect-PnPOnline "https://[yourdomain].sharepoint.com/[path]/[toyoursite]"

#Getting the Web:
$web = Get-PnPWeb

#Loading the alerts:
$web.Context.Load($web.Alerts)
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Loading the alert's list information:
$web.Alerts | % {$web.Context.Load($_.List)}
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Just showing the alerts of the list before the change:
$web.Alerts | ?  {$_.List.Title -eq $listTitle}

#Turning off the alerts:
$web.Alerts | ?  {$_.List.Title -eq $listTitle} | % {$_.Status = 'Off'; $_.UpdateAlert()}
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

To turn them back on, just change `'Off'` to `'On'` in the end.

I have tested it and **the changes while the alert is off are not sent to the users even if they configured their alerts to be sent aggregated daily** (the entries while the alert is off are not registered to be sent later), so success!

---

I decided to provide my own, instead of just accepting his answer, as my code is **disabling the alerts for a specific list** (as requested in the question), it is shorter (while still being easy to read) and it is not using hard-coded username nor direct references to assemblies that you would need to download and remember where they are.

As you can see in the first lines, the script is using SharePoint Patterns & Practices PowerShell (more information here: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell), which is quite famous and a common practice in the area.

If you just want to install it, you can use the following command:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

Or, in case you don't have admin priviledges:

```
Install-Module  SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 1):

During the maintenance time, if these alerts were enabled, then while doing a bulk upload, the end users will be getting a huge number of mails. Hence, we need to disable the alerts, not deleting the alerts. For that, there is no direct option on the screen, but PowerShell does that.

```
Import-Module   'C:\Milind\PRACTICE SOURCE CODES\Office365.Console\packages\Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.16.1.6420.1200\lib\net45\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Import-Module   'C:\Milind\PRACTICE SOURCE CODES\Office365.Console\packages\Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.16.1.6420.1200\lib\net45\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

 #Mysite URL
 $site = 'https://**********.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite/'

 #Admin User Principal Name
 $admin = 'milind@********.OnMicrosoft.Com'

 #Get Password as secure String
 $password = Read-Host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString

 #Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
 $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

 #Authenticate
 $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
 $context.Credentials = $credentials

 $context.Load($context.Web)
 $context.Load($context.Web.Alerts)

 $context.ExecuteQuery()

 foreach($alert in $context.Web.Alerts)
 {
     if($alert.Status -eq 'On')
     {
 #The below will enable the Alert
 # $alert.Status = 'On' 

 #The below will disable the Alert
         $alert.Status = 'Off'
         $alert.UpdateAlert()
         $context.Load($alert)
         $context.ExecuteQuery()
     }
     Write-Host $alert.Title + "-" + $alert.Status
 }

 Write-Host $context.Web.Alerts.Count
```

Comment: @Pedro Lorentz did it helps you, if yest than upvote it

Comment: This is disabling alerts for the whole site, i need to disable the alerts only for that specific list. I think that it can probably be changed for that. The task to do that was postponed for next week, so I have not tested it yet.

Comment: in foreach loop check for Web and listName and then execute the ahead

Answer (score 0):

In case this solution doesn't work for anyone, I have a workaround that will not fire off the user created list alerts. If you are removing the list items, take note of who has permissions to the list and then remove the permissions for everyone on that list. Go in and delete the list items and then my preference has been to wait 20 min or so and then re-stablish the permissions that were removed prior to deleting the list items. If you need to modify list items without the alerts going out, you can also follow the above steps or use the PowerShell PnP Set-PnPListItem cmdlet using the -UpdateType parameter with the "System Update" value.